# NSDate change to local format xcode 5.1.1

Tags: nsdateformatter, nslocale, xcode5.1.1

I selected the **Arabic** date in my device but i have to send the that date to the server in **US format**.
Please help me.
I'm using this code ::

```
  NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    strCreatedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    NSDate *oldTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strCreatedDate];
    NSString *estDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:oldTime];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code for date formate..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"your date formate"];

NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```